# I can't figure where is the problem with my graphql request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, graphql

I'm getting bad request code every time i try to send data query in graphql,

[image]

and I can't figure if the problem from the resolver or from the input,

below is the resolver :

```
const addTranslationTableAdminResolver = async (args, context, info) => {
  checkAuth(context);
  const videocardId = args.input.videoCardId;
  const videoLink = args.input.videoLink;
  const orgId = args.input.orgId;
  await context.dao.createTranslationTable({
    id,
    orgId,
    videocardId,
    dateTime,
    videoLink,
  });
  return {
    statusMessage: 'SUCCESS',
  };
};
```

and the data-object access as below:

```
const createTranslationTable = async ({ orgId, videocardId, videoLink }) => {
  const queryString = `INSERT INTO translation_table (org_id, video_id,request_date,video_link)
                              VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *`;
  const dateTime = new Date();
  const values = [orgId, videocardId, dateTime, videoLink];
  const result = await query(queryString, values);
  if (result && result.rows.length === 1) {
    return getAllTranslationObject(result.rows[0]);
  }
};
```

when I'm trying to send data query i'm getting the same error as above.

```
const createTransaltionVideoCard = (orgId, videoCardId, videoLink) => {
  return gqBackOfficeClient.mutate({
    mutation: gql`
    mutation {
      createTranslationTable(input: {
        orgId: ${orgId},
        videocardId: ${videoCardId},
        videoLink :"${videoLink}"
      }) {
        statusMessage
     }
      }
          
        `,
  });
};



 const handleTranslationButtonClick = (orgId, videoCardId, videoLink) => {
    setIsTranslationButtonClicked(true);
    createTransaltionVideoCard({
      orgId,
      videoCardId,
      videoLink,
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  };
```

Comment: just to update , solved this issue, it was a problem with resolvers, and now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to update , solved this issue, it was a problem with resolvers, and now its working fine –

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).